# Divide number by WEEKNUM to get the rate per remaining weeks of this year

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am trying to divide a number by the total remaining number of weeks and have it calculate as the weeks' progress. I am using the formula `=D58/today(WEEKNUM(1/5/2019,0))`, but I keep getting an `#N/A` error. Any suggestions? I am trying to keep it in a single cell.

Comment: Remaining total number of weeks in what? Can you add some sample data with what output you're expecting?

Comment: I actually figured it out not too long ago. Specifically I was inquiring about a school project in which I had a total amount of Sale goals to hit year end Quotas. I wanted to figure out how much I needed to do per week, as the year progresses.. The formula I used was =$728,000/(ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())-52)*-1 . The -1 was just to make make it a positive number

Answer (score 1):

```
=A2/(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-52)*-1
```

[image: 6]

### _______________________________________________________________

- to roundup undividable tasks:

```
=ROUNDUP(A3/(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-52)*-1, 0)
```

Comment: what is the difference between ISOWeekNum and WeekNum ?

Comment: @Jordan basically this: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eiM0.png**